# To-Do app with multiple lists, all visible on one screen

Tags: windows, todo

I'm looking for a Windows incarnation of AntLogic's [To-Do Lists](https://www.antlogic.com/apps/todo-lists) (which is for MacOS only), an extremely simple To-Do app with one (to me) killer feature: You can have multiple To-Do lists on one screen, and move them around and resize them as you please (like in your typical post-it app).

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Features:

- Other than the "all tasks on one screen feature" which is a *must*, the app is standard To-Do app fare (cross out finished tasks, reminders, important tasks in red, not that much more)
- Mobile sync (either with a companion app or Google tasks/whatever) would be a **huge** plus
- XML export, automatic backup, etc. etc. are welcome additions (there should be *some* way to export tasks into a standard format)
- Budget: the MacOS app cost $5, but I'm open to suggestions in any price range.

Comment: This is my first question here, I hope it's ok!

Comment: Welcome aboard :-) Your question is just fine. There is a [related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/63148/is-there-any-good-personal-task-management-app-which-can-show-all-tasks-on-one-p)

Comment: This thread is still relevant since I have been searching for this kind of app forever.
Coincidentally, I just stumbled upon https://columns.app which looks awesome. I’m searching everywhere, there’s no paying plans, looks absolutely free.

Answer (score 2):

Trello is an awesome ToDo app available on android, IOS and web.
In Trello you can also add your friends to different rooms and show them what you are planning for and ...
[image: Trello screenshot]

By the way, it is totally free.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a web app to manage my Google Tasks in a Trello like fashion.

it's called [TasksBoard](https://tasksboard.app), try it out and let me know what you think ;)

Here's a screenshot
[image: TasksBoard screenshot]

Cheers

Comment: Your app TasksBoard is exactly what I was looking for. It's simple and easy to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few out there, it may be worth considering:

- https://www.trello.com
- https://asana.com/
- https://monday.com/
- https://clickup.com/

Trello is by far the simplest app, but all the others allow for lists/tasks to be created.