# Is there any good personal task management app which can show all tasks on one page?

Tags: productivity, task-management

I am going through some famous task management apps like wunderlist, google tasks, microsoft todo but none of them provides one feature I need.

Each of them give a feature to create many folders and add tasks but to see tasks in them it needs the effort to click on the folder and then see the tasks. Its really frustrating to click on each folder.

Is there any app which gives following features:

1. Show all tasks on single page
2. Show subtasks of those task also without needing to click on each task.

I just want to open the window and phew... no more clicks required to see any more detail.
Problem with trello is that it doesn't show subtasks and doesn't allow list below list which keeps the page empty.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: I like [Things](https://culturedcode.com/things/) on iOS/OSX

Comment: Considering software recs' 44% unanswered rate, I'd suggest to not do only that but rework this question here so maybe we can figure out how to not ever need something like this.

Comment: While it does not do everything you want, I would suggest taking a look at asana.

Comment: [related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36139/to-do-app-with-multiple-lists-all-visible-on-one-screen)

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a web app to manage my Google Tasks in a Trello like fashion.

it's called [TasksBoard](https://tasksboard.app), try it out and let me know what you think ;)

Here's a screenshot
[image: TasksBoard screenshot]

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [meistertask](https://www.meistertask.com), I would be lost without it now. Easy to customize and best of all it is free.